# Graph api explorer - what is the "with" modifier

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-field-expansion

In [Facebook Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), there is a "with" modifier (along with since, filter, limit etc). 

What is it used for?

Comment: Probably people tagged in a post?

Comment: I thought so to, but something like me/home?filter={some_filter}&with={uid} is the same as without specifying the with modifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `with` modifier to filter posts that contains a location attatched to them.

From [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home):

`You can retrieve only posts with a location attached by adding with=location to the URL parameters:`

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?with=location

Works for feed (Wall Posts), posts (Posts by the user himself) and home (News Feed).

Comment: Do you know by chance, if you can use the `with` modifier for other filterings too? Is there a list of possible values you can pass as `with`? Is `location` the only one?